# Button Attributes is not working in Iphone

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, nsattributedstring

I have a `UIButton` in a nib file`(.xib)` which uses the **Attributed Title** from IB, but does not reflected when runs on device.

**My configuration for button is as follow:**

[image]

but not reflected.

Comment: What do you mean by **not reflected.**

Comment: It works on my Xcode.

Comment: I think you might have to change the state from default to custom.

Comment: my button state config is Default, and it works with no problem.

Comment: @XuYin,Thanks for reply but I don't do anything with code

Comment: @XuYin, yes it not only works for custom font.

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be you have again set the UIButton title by programmatically. If you set your button title from IB, and again set it from code. In runtime it take title from code.

Comment: Thanks for reply but I don't do anything with code.